Moveit OMPL - Constrained Path Planning
I am working on a project to make BLUEROV2 autonomous. I was wondering if I can constrain the floating joint of ompl to only rotate as yaw, and constrain roll and pitch motion. Can I do this? Please need help. Thanks!
I tried changing the srdf file to constrain this, but I didnt find any ways.
